# Displaying Data From Two SQL Tables Syntax Explanation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, union

I'm new to SQL and trying to better understand the syntax of displaying data from two tables. I've been reading through a lot of tutorials ( http://databases.about.com/od/sql/l/aajoins2.htm ) but I'm still a little foggy on the subject.

My desired behavior is to display data from two SQL tables within a single html table. It would be simple, except table 2 has a few more pieces of information being stored in it. Here is the data being stored in each table.

Table 1 (trainingaidreturns)
-Submit Date, ID, customer_name, product_name, _product_condition
Table 2
-Submit Date, ID, customer_name, product_name, _product_condition, club_type, club_flex, club_loft, club_hand

I've successfully used a union to display matching row data from the two tables, but I also need to display the club_type, club_flex, club_loft, and club_hand from the second table. When I plug it in, nothing displays.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition
FROM trainingaidreturns
UNION 
SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition
FROM clubreturns");
```

And here is what I essentially need the code to do.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition
FROM trainingaidreturns
UNION 
SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition, club_type, club_hand, club_flex, club_loft
FROM clubreturns");
```

I think I need to use a join, but I don't understand the syntax. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to run the same query in a query editor you'd get an error message of something to the effect of "columns and datatypes for columns must match on both ends of your union"

to get around this you can change:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition
FROM trainingaidreturns
UNION 
SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition, club_type, club_hand, club_flex, club_loft
FROM clubreturns");
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition, club_type, club_hand, club_flex, club_loft
FROM clubreturns
UNION
SELECT SubmitDate, ID, customer_name, product_name, product_condition, null, null, null, null
FROM trainingaidreturns");
```

or similar.  Basically it makes "placeholder/null" values in the columns that aren't matching table to table

EDIT:

here's a fiddle demonstrating the concept: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a152/1

Comment: Changed the period to a comma after your 3rd null and moved the table with more data to the first select and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, another thing you could do rather than switching the two queries around (because sometimes you will have some in tbl1 and not in tbl2 AND some in tbl2 but not in tbl1) is specify "null as club_type" (as an example)